# Excel 2007: How to infer the range to use in a function from that used in another function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

My document has two relevant columns that I regularly do math on: Hours (B) and Client (D). I create weekly totals of the hours with the function `=SUM(B15:B40)`. However, I also total the hours for one specific client by evaluating the Client column in another cell with the function `=SUMIF(D15:D40, ("<>Example"), B15:B40)`

Next week, when I want to do this again, I copy and paste these summing cells and then update the range. (The number of rows in a given week is not predictable.) However, I have to update the range for both functions.

Is there a way in Excel 2007 to have one function infer the range it should evaluate from another function?

Is that a way in Excel 2007 to infer the range from another part of the function? (So, in the example `=SUMIF(D15:D40, ("<>Example"), B15:B40)`, is there a way to only specify the `15` and `40` once?)

Answer (score 1):

Oh yes.

Use the `INDIRECT()` function. Say you enter `15` and `40` in cells A1 and A2, then the formula in some cell. It would go like so:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("D" & A1 & ":D" & A2), ("<>6"), INDIRECT("B" & A1 & ":B" & A2))
```

You are building the string `D15:D40` inside its parentheses, then it takes that valid address and makes it into a real reference. So then you simply go to A1 and A2 to change the start and end of your current range. Much easier than editing a formula or 60 each week.

There are other ways, for less straightforward situations. Using `FORMULATEXT()`, for example, you can read a different cell's formula as a string (including leading `=`) and strip of the leading characters right up to some range in it, and all the lagging characters that start after that range leaving only the range that cell used. `INDIRECT()` then lets you turn it into a real reference for that second cell to use. In this way, you are guaranteed both cells are using that precise range. Sounds esoteric, but I have several places it suits best. Normally, you'd build both and get matching that way, but sometimes it is hard to build one so...

Unfortunately, there is nothing to do the same for a string to change to a real formula. Not without some kind of macro, even if the old Excel 4 macro commands which Excel now more fully treats as macros, not haphazardly handling them and letting cracks exist. Sigh...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).